# Add objective c code to swift file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to add somehow the following objective-c code to AppDelegate.swift file into the function.

```
    // Define some colors.
    UIColor *darkGray = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    UIColor *lightGray = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    // Navigation bar background.
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:darkGray];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:lightGray];

    // Color of typed text in the search bar.
    NSDictionary *searchBarTextAttributes = @{
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: lightGray,
        NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]
    };
    [UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]]
    .defaultTextAttributes = searchBarTextAttributes;

    // Color of the placeholder text in the search bar prior to text entry.
    NSDictionary *placeholderAttributes = @{
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: lightGray,
        NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]
    };

    // Color of the default search text.
    // NOTE: In a production scenario, "Search" would be a localized string.
    NSAttributedString *attributedPlaceholder =
        [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Search"
    attributes:placeholderAttributes];
    [UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]]
    .attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder;
```

What is the best solution for it? Should I just create Objective-C file or header?

Comment: Just translate it to swift and write it in the AppDelegate.swift directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rough translation to Swift...no tested.

```
// Define some colors.
var darkGray: UIColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
var lightGray: UIColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
// Navigation bar background.
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = darkGray
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = lightGray
    // Color of typed text in the search bar.
var searchBarTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: lightGray, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())]
UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = searchBarTextAttributes
    // Color of the placeholder text in the search bar prior to text entry.
var placeholderAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: lightGray, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())]

   // Color of the default search text.
    // NOTE: In a production scenario, "Search" would be a localized string.
var attributedPlaceholder: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: placeholderAttributes)
UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I'm just not too good in converting from Objective-C to Swift.

Comment: Note that most of the time you don't need to define the explicit type of a variable – just let Swift infer it. Also you should be using `let` for variables that you don't mutate.